# Optimizing image loading with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm lost and need some guidance with optimizing image loading on a website.
I'm currently working on a simple landing page for a small business, and I have 48 pictures to display, by sets of 12.

I have four buttons, and each button shows a different set of images.

My problem is that the images I was provided with are large, and even when I put the image inside a 200x200 container (which I guess not really doing anything to the image size itself, am I correct?) clicking a button have a noticeable lag until displaying the new set of images, it effects the whole page (for example, the Bootstrap Carousel I'm using is getting laggy until the images are displayed).

I tried to search, and found [JavaScript-Load-Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image#image-scaling) but I couldn't really understand how I need to work with it, as I'm not using FileReader.
All the images I have are local, in the project folder.

This is how I change between the images:

```
//This function is getting called when an optionbtn is tapped,
//and calls the other function to create the full effect of loading the new images.
function handleOptionButtonClick(buttonId){
    changeOptionButtonColor(buttonId);
    switch(buttonId){
        case 'button1':
            loadImagesToArray('hospitalityTrays');
            break;
        case 'button2':
            loadImagesToArray('eventManagement');
            break;
        case 'button3':
            loadImagesToArray('cakes');
            break;
        case 'button4':
            loadImagesToArray('meats');
            break;
        default:
            loadImagesToArray('food');
    }
    fadeAndDisplayMainGrid();
}

//Loading the sources for the new images and setting them in the array
function loadImagesToArray(imagesOf){
    let src = './Images' + '/' + imagesOf + '/';
    for(var index=0; index<imagesToDisplay.length; index++){
        let newImageSrc = src + index + '.jpg';
        imagesToDisplay[index] = newImageSrc;
    }
}

//Displaying the images we got in the array, will be called after loadImagesToArray
function displayImagesFromArray(){

    let myGridCells = $('.foodImage');

    for(var index=0; index<myGridCells.length; index++){
        myGridCells[index].src = imagesToDisplay[index];
    }

}

//Fading out the current grid, changing the img srcs and fading the grid in.
function fadeAndDisplayMainGrid() { 
    $("#picturesGrid").fadeOut(500).promise().done(function(){
        displayImagesFromArray();
        $("#picturesGrid").fadeIn(500);
    });
}
```

`handleOptionButtonClick` - is the function that gets called when the user clicks a button.

`loadImagesToArray` - is getting the name of the images set to display, and fills an array with the sources of those images from the project folder (each category of images has it's own folder)

`displayImagesFromArray` - is taking the sources I have inside the array that was filled by `loadImagesToArray`, and changing my imgs srcs inside a grid.

`fadeAndDisplayMainGrid` - is fading the grid out, calling displayImagesFromArray so the src is changed and fading the grid in.

Comment: Can't you resize the images to the size you're actually displaying them in?

Comment: I thought about it, but in the future, I will need to add a click function to the image to display it in full size.

Comment: Two files then, a thumbnail and the original.

Comment: Thats an option, but I would still like to try and optimize this current state. I will try to get smaller images for a thumbnail but I don't have it now.

Comment: @radulfr is correct - the usual way to do this is to provide a thumbnail, which loads quickly, and a secondary image that contains the detail. You may want to write a service that creates the thumbnails when the larger images are uploaded to the site.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will try to reduce my images size's, I don't have thumbnail nor an option (a fast one, I guess) to create a thumbnail for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the browser still needs to download the whole image then it resizes based on your styling so changing width and height in CSS won't help. There are several things you can do to speed this up.

- Resize images based on the actual height and width you'd like them displayed at using another program, switch between images based on size of users viewport

  - image-full.jpg
  - image-200-200.jpg
- Use progressive images (option when saving in Photoshop, Assetizr and other programs)
- Use WebP format and have JPG format as fallback
- Reduce size of file using image minification, some [examples from google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/automating-image-optimization)

Comment: Thank you! I will try and reduce the size of the files as I don't have smaller versions of them, I tried looking on the internet for a thumbnail generator or something, but nothing worked well enough.

Comment: For small projects I optimize my images using [Assetizr](https://assetizr.com/), you throw the images you want in there and you can choose the size, format and quality then you can include those optimized versions in your project folder along with the full sized originals

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.